# Security alert: App contains embedded private keys or keystore files

Tags: android, apk, google-play-services, google-play

Recently got a mail from Google:

> This is a notification that your app(s) com.myapp, contains one or
>   more private keys or keystore files embedded in its published apk as
>   listed at the end of this email. These embedded items can be accessed
>   by third parties, which can raise a variety of different security
>   concerns depending on what the key is used for. For example, if the
>   private key is the signing key for your application, a third party
>   could sign and distribute apps that replace your authentic apps or
>   corrupt them. Such a party could also sign and distribute apps under
>   your identity.
>
> As a general security practice, we strongly recommend against
>   embedding private keys and keystore files in apps, even if the keys
>   are password protected or obfuscated. The most effective way to
>   protect your private key and keystore files is not to circulate them.
>
> Please remove your private keys and keystore files from your app at
>   your earliest convenience. Each app is different, but if you aren't
>   sure how to locate the keys and keystore files in your app, you can
>   try looking for files with the "keystore" file extension and grepping
>   for "PRIVATE KEY". For more information about keeping your key secure,
>   please see
>   https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html.
>
> You have a responsibility as a developer to secure your private key
>   properly, at all times. Please note, while it's unclear whether these
>   specific issues affect your application, applications with
>   vulnerabilities that expose users to risk of compromise may be
>   considered “dangerous products” and subject to removal from Google
>   Play.
>
> To check if subsequent versions of your apps contain private keys,
>   please see the Alerts section of the Google Play Developer Console at
>   https://play.google.com/apps/publish/#AlertsPlace.
>
> Affected apps and samples of embedded items:
>   repack/org/bouncycastle/openssl/test/data/dsa/openssl_dsa_aes128_cbc.pem
>   repack/org/bouncycastle/openssl/test/data/dsa/openssl_dsa_aes128_cfb.pem
>   repack/org/bouncycastle/openssl/test/data/dsa/openssl_dsa_aes128_ecb.pem
>   repack/org/bouncycastle/openssl/test/data/dsa/openssl_dsa_aes128_ofb.pem
>   repack/org/bouncycastle/openssl/test/data/dsa/openssl_dsa_aes192_cbc.pem

I am using a library (jar file) which contains the above .pem files. These files have the keyword 'PRIVATE KEY'. I am not revealing my private key or keystore anywhere in the APK package.
What can I do to address this issue? What change do I make to the JAR file or my app APK?
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a very similar message from Google today regarding this. Upon investigation I found the same files you have listed in one of my jars. I have resolved this issue by deleting the whole openssl folder from the jar with the following console command.

```
zip --delete AFFECTEDJAR.jar "repack/org/bouncycastle/openssl/*"
```

I would suggest checking there are no java classing in that folder before you run this. In my case there was nothing but test data anyway.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did the same. It had .class files in it. So left those files and deleted the rest. Let's hope Google accepts it.

Comment: did they accept you modification? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @ghostrider3 Yeah after releasing an update without those files the alert dismissed itself

Comment: @drspaceboo I am also facing the same issue. Could you please provide me the steps how to do that command in mac.

Comment: @Android_dev That command is pretty much what you need once you know where the files are coming from. I think I just found them by using Android Studio to search.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that you don't need these files in the application.  Just remove them from the export process when you are releasing the application.  I am assuming that these are inside the project directly for ease of passing around the application and keeping them near the project.

If this is the case, just move the keystores outside the package and reference them from a separate directly when needed so that they are not packaged in.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step instruction on how to get rid of this msg- http://pctechnique.com/index.php/android-apps/2-uncategorised/31-security-alert-for-pem-file-and-keystore-in-your-apk